# Is there any way to intercept function definition in global object of v8 context?

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm trying to clear `v8::Context` to reuse it later (except of creating new one) for better performance.

I have protected all built-ins with `write/enum/configure` flags setted to `false`.
After running any scripts, I'm trying to iterate all `configurable` properties in `Context.Global` and delete them.

The main issue is that `Script::Run` is defining all functions inside script as `configurable: false` properties in `v8::Context`, so it cannot be deleted by `Global->Delete(...)`

I have tried to setup an `Interceptor` on `Global` object, but it haven't helped (GenericNamedPropertyDefinerCallback haven't called after `Script::Run`)

Code example:

```cpp
#include <v8.h>
#include <libplatform/libplatform.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define trace(s) std::cout << s << std::endl
#define traceh(s) trace("===== " << std::setw(64) << s << " =====")

const char* _script = "function test_func() { return \"something\"; }";

std::string getString(const v8::Local<v8::Value>& value) {
    auto* pIsolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
    return *v8::String::Utf8Value(pIsolate, value);
}

v8::Local<v8::UnboundScript> compileScript(const char* script) {
    auto* pIsolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
    v8::EscapableHandleScope hScope(pIsolate);

    auto source_str = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(pIsolate, script);
    v8::ScriptCompiler::Source source(source_str);
    v8::TryCatch TryCatch(pIsolate);
    auto mScript = v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnboundScript(pIsolate, &source);
    if (mScript.IsEmpty()) {
        trace("failed to compile script: " << getString(TryCatch.Exception()));
        return {};
    }
    return hScope.Escape(mScript.ToLocalChecked());
}

void protectContext(v8::Local<v8::Context>& context) {
    traceh("protecting context");
    auto* pIsolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
    v8::HandleScope hScope(pIsolate);
    auto Global = context->Global();
    auto mPropNames = Global->GetPropertyNames(context, v8::KeyCollectionMode::kIncludePrototypes,
                                               v8::PropertyFilter::ALL_PROPERTIES, v8::IndexFilter::kSkipIndices);
    if (mPropNames.IsEmpty()) {
        trace("failed to get property names of global object");
        return;
    }
    auto propNames = mPropNames.ToLocalChecked();
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < propNames->Length(); ++i) {
        auto keyVal = propNames->Get(context, i).ToLocalChecked();
        auto key = v8::Local<v8::Name>::Cast(keyVal);
        auto prev_attribs = Global->GetPropertyAttributes(context, key).ToChecked();
        auto val = Global->Get(context, key).ToLocalChecked();
        v8::PropertyDescriptor descriptor(val, false);
        descriptor.set_enumerable(false);
        descriptor.set_configurable(false);
        v8::TryCatch TryCatch(pIsolate);
        auto mResult = Global->DefineProperty(context, key, descriptor);
        if (mResult.IsNothing()) {
            trace("failed to protect property: " << getString(TryCatch.Exception()));
        }
        auto lResult = !mResult.IsNothing() && mResult.ToChecked();
        auto attribs = Global->GetPropertyAttributes(context, key).ToChecked();
        trace("protected: " << std::setw(31) << getString(key) << " - " << (lResult ? "ok" : "fl") <<
              "; prev-attribs=" << std::setw(2) << prev_attribs <<
              "; attribs=" << std::setw(2) << attribs);
    }
}

void clearContext(v8::Local<v8::Context>& context) {
    traceh("clearing context");
    auto* pIsolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
    v8::HandleScope hScope(pIsolate);
    auto Global = context->Global();
    auto mPropNames = Global->GetPropertyNames(context, v8::KeyCollectionMode::kIncludePrototypes,
                                               v8::PropertyFilter::ALL_PROPERTIES, v8::IndexFilter::kSkipIndices);
    if (mPropNames.IsEmpty()) {
        trace("failed to get property names of global object");
        return;
    }
    auto propNames = mPropNames.ToLocalChecked();
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < propNames->Length(); ++i) {
        auto key = propNames->Get(context, i).ToLocalChecked();
        auto attribs = Global->GetPropertyAttributes(context, key).ToChecked();
        v8::TryCatch TryCatch(pIsolate);
        auto mResult = Global->Delete(context, key);
        if (TryCatch.HasCaught()) {
            trace("failed to delete property: " << getString(TryCatch.Exception()));
        }
        auto lResult = !mResult.IsNothing() && mResult.ToChecked();
        trace("deleted: " << std::setw(33) << getString(key) << " - " << (lResult ? "ok" : "fl") <<
              "; prev-attribs=" << std::setw(2) << attribs);
    }
}

int main() {
    v8::V8::InitializeICU();
    auto platform_ptr = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform_ptr.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();

    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    auto* pIsolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
    {
        v8::Isolate::Scope iScope(pIsolate);
        {
            v8::HandleScope hScope(pIsolate);
            v8::Local<v8::UnboundScript> UnboundScript;
            {
                auto Context = v8::Context::New(pIsolate);
                {
                    v8::Context::Scope cScope(Context);
                    UnboundScript = compileScript(_script);
                }
            }
            {
                auto Context = v8::Context::New(pIsolate);
                {
                    v8::Context::Scope cScope(Context);

                    protectContext(Context);

                    auto Script = UnboundScript->BindToCurrentContext();
                    trace("Script::Run - " << (Script->Run(Context).IsEmpty() ? "fail" : "ok"));

                    clearContext(Context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    pIsolate->Dispose();

    v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
    return 0;
}
```

After running it under v8-7.5 (latest chrome-stable) I'm getting

```sh
deleted:                         test_func - fl; prev-attribs= 4
```

Deletion failed since 4 is `configure: false`

Comment: Can you post an example (including both embedding code and a script) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @jmrk, I've added code example with tracing to console

Comment: When protecting the builtins, did you also make each of them non-extensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an interceptor in your code, but that aside...

The `GenericNamedPropertyDefinerCallback` will be invoked when a script uses `Object.defineProperty(global, name, ...)`, when `name` is not an array index.

I hadn't realized that regular `function foo() {...}` definitions also get installed as non-configurable (TIL ☺ ). To intercept those, you'll need two more interceptors: a `GenericNamedPropertyQueryCallback` that returns `true` (indicating "this property exists already"), and a `GenericNamedPropertySetterCallback`, which, if the query callback said the property exists, will be called to "overwrite" it. Note that you will have to take care of the actual storing of the property. Or you can simply block all attempts to set properties on the global object, forcing all code to run inside an IIFE `(function() { /* all code here */ })()`. Come to think of it, maybe applying such a wrapping in your embedding code is an easier way to achieve your goal... except for `globalThis`, I suppose.

For completeness: if you want to intercept integer-indexed properties/functions as well, you'll need the corresponding indexed interceptors (`IndexedPropertySetterCallback` etc).

I've pieced this together from looking at V8's source, but haven't tried it myself. Let me know if it doesn't work, and if so include your code please.

Comment: I've tried setter + definer callbacks, after `Script::Run` setter callback is called, so I can intercept it and redefine with other flags. Oh, no, it's recursion since I can't check flags for that callback :(
I'm done creating spikes. Would be better to refactor project (using IIFE like u said) or create new clear context every time. 
Another issue is that script has many `function foo(){}` items and all of them are executed at different moments (1 script -> many IIFE scripts).
Thanks for your answers a lot, anyway. Have a nice day ;)